# PHP and ADODB - ADODB throwing an error when uploading content

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb

I have the following code (truncated a touch as the css is irrelevant) that I am trying to submit to my MSSQL server. Problem is, it just throws up an error every thing I try. The code is split over 2 PHP pages. Page 1 has the form and Page 2 has the connection data and string.

Page 1 (I have a js function that duplicates the text in the span sections so you get a preview of it before you submit which is why theres the extra at the bottom):

```
<form action="create.php" name="frmAdd" method="post">
    <div class="news"><a id="news1"></a>
        <div class="newstitle">
            <h3>
        <input id="headline" type="text" maxlength="50" name="headlinetxt" />
    </h3>
        </div>  <em><h5>
        <input id="timestamp" type="text" name="timestamptxt" />
    </h5></em>

        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p>
            <textarea id="news" type="text" name="newstxt"></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="news"><a id="news1"></a>
        <div class="newstitle">
            <h3>
        <span id="headlinedisp" /></span>
    </h3>
        </div>  <em><h5>
        <span id="timestampdisp" /></span>
    </h5></em>

        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p><span id="newsdisp" /></span>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="button" onClick="document.forms['frmAdd'].submit();">Submit</div>
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
<head>
<title>News Edit</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include('/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
$db = NewADOConnection('odbc_mssql');
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=sage;Database=live;";
$db -> Connect($dsn,'user','pass');
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO website_news VALUES ('".$_POST["headlinetxt"]."','".$_POST["timestamptxt"]."','".$_POST["newstxt"]."') ";
$upld = $db->Execute($strSQL);
If($upld)
{
echo("Complete");
}
else
{
echo("Error");
}
$db->Close();
$db = null
 ?>
</body>
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may not be connecting? I assume it is an issue with line 10 of my page 2 (where it compiles the SQL) as this was giving me seperate errors earlier in my debug. I do have a unique ID in column 1, but this should be auto-populated in theory although dont know if I will need to add this in with something like ...IDENTITY,'".$POST_["headline.... etc. as really that should not be necessary. Is there a better way to debug different parts of the code rather than just showing Error too? (EDIT: Found out last night I can use objErr the same way I can use Err in VB. Didn't think of it at all. Will test that and see what I get)

(PS. A slight side question that I will post seperately if requested. I have the duplicate function working fine in theory (i.e. it works in JSFiddle), but as soon as I take it and put it into place I cannot get it to work on the site itself, running in Chrome, running the same spec jQuery as the fiddle. Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bmgh1985/XcScd/)

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out (realised I could use Err.Description as in VB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I figured it out (realised I could use Err.Description as in VB)